# How to solve error when creating android apk with FCM in ionic project?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I have have created a ionic project  with FCM instlled.But after installing FCM it shows error ':processDebugGoogleServices'.I have updated SDK. How to solve thatand build apk[image]

```html
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.2.0.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line at the end in your build.gradle file and rebuild your project.

> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

**NOTE: Please ensure that you add the above line at the end of the line**

Check out the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk) for sample.

Answer (score 0):

"To resolve this error, go to the Project-->platform..>android-->.gradlefile
and Modify"

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'*  
}
```

}
// apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// class must be used instead of id(string) to be able to apply plugin from non-root gradle file
apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin